# Azure Mobile Services AutoMapper HttpResponseException at Query()

Tags: c#, azure, automapper, azure-mobile-services

I tried to comple this [Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/19/mapping-between-database-types-and-client-type-in-the-net-backend-using-automapper.aspx). The content is just simple Mapping of an object to a `DTO`.

I initialized my Mapper at `WebConfig.cs`

```
 public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            // Define a map from the database type TodoItem to 
            // client type TodoItemDto. Used when getting data.
            cfg.CreateMap<TodoItem, TodoItemDto>();
            // Define a map from the client type to the database
            // type. Used when inserting and updating data.
            cfg.CreateMap<TodoItemDto, TodoItem>();
        });

        // To display errors in the browser during development, uncomment the following
        // line. Comment it out again when you deploy your service for production use.
        // config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        Database.SetInitializer(new my_Initializer());
    }
```

I added my DTO-Class as shown in the Tutorial and prepared my Controller

```
 public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItemDto>
{


    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        my_Context context = new my_Context();
        DomainManager = new SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager(context, Request, Services);
    }

    public IQueryable<TodoItemDto> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
            return Query();
    }
    public SingleResult<TodoItemDto> GetTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }
    public Task<TodoItemDto> PatchTodoItem(string id, Delta<TodoItemDto> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItemDto item)
    {
        TodoItemDto current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
    public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

I went step by step through the tutorial. I really tried to do exactly the same.
But in the end I allways get an `HttpResponseException` when I call `GetAllTodoItems()`.

//Edit: I get my `HttpResponseException` when I call `GetAllTodoItems()` at `return Query()`.

I can see the my two TodoItems (that I seeded) in the Context. So my Context isn't empty.
My `DomainManager` is the same as in the tutorial.

I dont even map different values. My models are simmilar as in the first chapter of the tutorial.

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}

public class TodoItemDto : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping looks soo easy and I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Man your code looks good. As i see it maybe the DomainManager have something wrong but cant tell if you dont post it or there is some problems with the EntityFramework( was common for me ).

You better provide us with the Error exception from the Stack.

Last check your database schema it must be exactly the same as your models including the EntityData properties or if you go Code-First set up your Initializer right. Use a ClearSchemaIfModelChanges Initializer. Maybe there are some changes since your Seed.

Answer (score 0):

i found out that i got a `MissingMethodException`in my `DomainManager`. I overwrited the `Query()` of my `DomainManager`and found it finally. Looks like I had some problems with the nugetpackages / versioning.